# how to do calculation in batch file for getting specified character

Tags: batch-file

How to get selected character

```
for %%A in (controls\vbalSGrid6.ocx) do (
    SET TEXT=%A%
    SET SUBSTRING=%TEXT:~9%
    echo %SUBSTRING%
)
```

this is giving echo is off but i only need `vbalsgrid6.ocx`.

Comment: Do you really need to do a substring operation or the only needed information is the name and extension of the file?

Comment: yes i really need substring operation..if we echo %%A it will give controls\vbalSGrid6.ocx but i need  vbalSGrid6.ocx for that i am doing string manupulation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The direct way**

```
set "text=controls\vbalscrid6.ocx"
set "substring=%text:~9%"
```

No need for the `for` command, unless you are iterating over a set of files or you don't want to use substring operations to get file names

**The easy way** to get the name and extension of the file

```
for %%a in (controls\vbalsgrid6.ocx) do set "fileName=%%~nxa"
```

`%%a` hold a reference to the file, and `%%~nxa` is the file name and extension of the referenced file

**A direct translation/corrected version** of your code (in this case, iterating over the list of files, but not needed)

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (controls\*.ocx) do (
    set "text=%%a"
    set "substring=!text:~9!"
    echo !substring!
)
```

When the batch parser reaches a line/block of code (code inside parenthesis), the full line/block is checked searching the places where a variable will be readed. All this reads are replaced with the value stored in the variable at parse time, **before** the line/block is executed. That means that if a variable changes its value inside a block, this changed value can not be accessed from inside the same block as the read operation on the variable was previously replaced with the initial value stored inside it.

To handle this case, delayed expansion is used. When delayed expansion is enabled, it is possible to change (where needed) the syntax to read a variable, from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that this read operation should be delayed until the command is executed.

The included code will work while there is no `!` in the name of the files. As delayed expansion is active, the parser will try to interpret any `!`, giving non expected results in some cases. It can be handled but sometimes it can be a bit tricky.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (controls\*.ocx) do (
        rem Retrieve the initial text. No problem as delayed expansion is disabled
        set "text=%%a"

        rem Enable delayed expansion to read the value in %text%. And ensure  
        rem it is disabled at the moment of the assignment to the substring var
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "substring="
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!text:~9!") do (endlocal & set "substring=%%b")

        rem We need delayed expansion enabled to read the changed value 
        rem If substring is empty, the previous endlocal was not executed and 
        rem there is no need for a new setlocal
        if defined substring setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(substring value=!substring!
        endlocal
    )
```